# Gap in mesh with the mirroring tool

Tags: modifiers, objects, mirror

I made something with the mirroring tool and now when I'm sculpting there's a gap between the two sides? How can I fix that?

Comment: Attaching a picture of your scene, even only a part of it showing the origin of the object as well as maybe the mirror modifier could help a lot in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. enable clipping
2. move the mesh slightly towards the middle (mirror axis) until the gap is closed and then back to the original position.

[image]